# Consuming SOAP web service with Two-Way TLS in SOAP UI

Tags: ssl, soapui, two-way

Im consuming a SOAP web service which has two-way SSL enabled. So I provided the client cert ( public key) to the server and configured the private key in my SOAP UI client project. Im able to consume the web service. But what I do not understand is, shouldn't I confugure server's certificate  ( that can be extacted using the endpoint through browser) explicitly in SOAP UI to enable two way SSL? or SOAPUI takes care of if automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in **SOAP UI** there is no SSL verification, since it's bypassing it by code. In the main class which starts the application, there is a call to `SecureTools.setTrustSSL();` in [`main(args[])` method.](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/next/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI.java#L923) If you check what [`SecureTools.setTrustSSL()` method does](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/next/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/tools/SecureTools.java), it modifies SSL default context factory with a trustManager which not does any check.

Comment: Hi @albciff, I did not expicitly add server's public key to my cacerts file either. Thats why I do not understand how SoapUI validates it. However this server sertificate is present in the SOAP request.

Comment: @Kevin you're right, I just checked the current SOAPUI version and there is no ssl validation, I review also old versions and seems that this change was made long ago, I remeber that I must change cacerts probably with first releases of soapui. I update my answer :).